# Should blank pages get a noindex tag or get deleted?

Tags: url, content, noindex

I was using webceo and came across pages that are blank. They of course have a URL, but no content.

So how do I know whether they should be noindexed (because they serve for functionality purposes) or if I should just delete them?

Comment: What does mean "webceo" ?

Comment: WebCEO is an online SEO and internet marketing platform.

Answer (score 2):

It is never a good idea to have blank pages with no content publicly accessible. Best practice is to remove the pages until such time as you have content for the pages, but as you state they are for functionality purposes only and so would never need to have content. In this case absolutely you can add noindex to the pages so that they don't count towards your SERP ranking in a negative way.

Answer (score 1):

It's also worth noting,

If you have links to these pages from another website or another page on your site, implement a 302 redirect to send users to a page of similar content would also be beneficial.